# SQL: Adding number while REPLACING string

Tags: sql-server

Good evening,

I need to replace a **"part of a string"** in a SQL column (**Column3**), I'm using the REPLACE build-in function  to accomplish this, but I need to ADD a leading number (**1**) to the original string (**Column2**), and I keep getting *"String or binary data would be truncated."*

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[Table1]
SET [Column3] = REPLACE(Column3, Column2, ('1' + Column2))
```

***One example:***

Column2: "0200"

Here is an example of what COLUMN3 string looks like:

Column3: "TEST DATA 0200"

Then after it gets replaced we need to show it like this: "TEST DATA 10200"
Notice the number now includes a leading "1"

HELP PLEASE!!!

Comment: Can you give examples of what you want the data to look like?  I don't think your code is doing what you want it to.

Comment: Column3: "TEST DATA 0200"
After it gets replaced we need to show: "TEST DATA 10200" @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting indicates that the resulting string is too big to fit in the "Data" column. You need to increase the size of "Data" to ensure the result will fit.

Try running this SELECT (instead of the UPDATE) to see what is happening

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(Column3, Column2, ('1' + Column2)) AS Result,
  DATALENGTH(REPLACE(Column3, Column2, ('1' + Column2))) AS ResultSize
FROM
  [database].[dbo].[Table1]
```

Comment: That column is set to nvarchar(255), plenty of space for the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this REPLACE function replaces in a recursive loop until it blows the size of the string. Let's say Column3 is a varchar(10), and contains "abcd". Column2 contains "b". Then, it will replace all occurrences of Column2 in Column3 for '1' + Column2.

First replacement ('b' for '1b'):

```
"a1bcd"
```

Second replacement:

```
"a11bcd"
```

It keeps going...

```
"a111bcd"
"a1111bcd"
"a11111bcd"
"a111111bcd"
```

Next time it will try to put a 11 character string on a varchar(10).

You should define your own function (using T-SQL) to run the string only once and, after replace, continue from after the replacement and not from the right next character.